# What could be causing pypyodbc to display this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I'm trying to switch my script over to pypyodbc from pyodbc. I have the following connect string:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Teradata ODBC DSN;DATABASE=*******;UID=******;PWD=******')
```

which works perfectly fine with pyodbc, but when I go to use pypyodbc instead, I get the following error:

```
  File "web.py", line 8, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Teradata ODBC DSN')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2437, in __init__
    AllocateEnv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1017, in AllocateEnv
    check_success(SQL_NULL_HANDLE, ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1011, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, ODBC_obj, ret, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 991, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError('', 'SQL_INVALID_HANDLE')
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('', 'SQL_INVALID_HANDLE')
```

What could be causing this to happen? I've seen some fixes that involve removing unnecessary quotes from the connect string, but I do not believe I have any here, so I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. have you found the solution for this issue?